# How can I override act_stock_return_picking button? In Odoo 9

Tags: xml, odoo-9, odoo

I want to override the "Reverse" button of stock picking to be only visible to stock.group_stock_manager.

I have used the same method as usual to override buttons:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
  <data>
    <record id="view_picking_form_extend" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">stock.picking.form.extend</field>
      <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
      <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_picking_form"/>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="/form/header/button[@name='%(act_stock_return_picking)d']" position="replace">
          <button name="%(act_stock_return_picking)d" string="Reverse" states="done" type="action" groups="stock.group_stock_manager"/>
        </xpath>
      </field>
    </record>
  </data>
</openerp>
```

But I get an error. It says the element cannot be located in parent view.

I have this in parent view:

```xml
<button name="%(act_stock_return_picking)d" string="Reverse" states="done" type="action" groups="base.group_user"/>
```

**Note:** If I override other button (without the '**%**' and '**d**' characters) it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have `%(xml_id)d`, it means that Odoo is going to search for the ID in the database of that XML ID (a `string`) and replace it by the PostgreSQL ID (a `integer`). So as every XML ID, if you haven't declared it inside your module, you have to specify the module where it was declared.

Try to write the module name where the source button was created before the name of the action, and don't replace the whole button if you're only modifying `groups`, use `attributes` instead, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
  <data>
    <record id="view_picking_form_extend" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">stock.picking.form.extend</field>
      <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
      <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_picking_form"/>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="/form/header/button[@name='%(stock.act_stock_return_picking)d']" position="attributes">
          <attribute name="groups">stock.group_stock_manager</attribute>
        </xpath>
      </field>
    </record>
  </data>
</openerp>
```